# Uncaught FacebookApiException: Unsupported operation thrown in

Tags: php, facebook-apps

I just built an application with the facebook graph API, and it's been running smoothly till now..

**Whenever I go to my website I'm now getting the error**

```
Uncaught FacebookApiException: Unsupported operation thrown on line 1254
```

**Here is line 1254**

```
$e = new FacebookApiException($result);
```

**When I ran a debug, this is what I got**

```
Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Inferred Property:
The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:  
The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:  
The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: An exception was thrown, and caught at line 1254.  Have you debugged it - what were the results?  What is the code doing at the time?

Comment: I added the debug results above.

Comment: Looks like you need to specify those 3 properties then?

Comment: I'll see if that does the trick.

Comment: Now they are all set, and it's still messing up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be logged in to the facebook app before you can call the graph API.
I had my API calls outside the

```
if ($user_is_logged_in) 
    do this
```

Should have known, but it was an honest mistake!